# how do I catch values returned from selenium web driver and store as one list

Tags: python-3.x, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, lis

I'm new to programming and I am using selenium to get data from scheduled matches from flashscore, I intend to assign each list returned from each loop to a variable so I can perform some calculations and also pop what I don't need.

Selenium web driver returns 2 elements on each for loop and the two elements are on different lists which makes it hard for me to access it or make the calculation

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://www.flashscore.com/'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
#closing Accept terms
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]').click()
#clicking on Scheduled matches
Scheduled = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[7]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]\
/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div').click()
time.sleep(2)
# getting all Scheduled matchs

try:
    #finding scheduled matches
    Scheduled = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@id, 'g_1')]")
    time.sleep(3)
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass

for value in Scheduled:
    window_home = driver.window_handles[0]
    value.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    window_1_open = driver.window_handles[1]
    driver.switch_to.window(window_1_open)
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        time.sleep(3)
        find_standing = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'STANDINGS')
        time.sleep(2)
        find_standing.click()
        time.sleep(3)
        get_match_values = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[starts-with(@class, \
        'ui-table__row table__row--selected')]")
        time.sleep(2)
        for values in get_match_values:
            print(values.text)
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(window_home)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(window_home)
```

Comment: Can you point us where the code is incorrect? This may help us

Comment: it prints 2 list because the the page only has two elements with same XPATH but i want know if i can join the list or assign each list to variable.  here is the line of code:   get_match_values = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[starts-with(@class, \
        'ui-table__row table__row--selected')]")
        time.sleep(2)
        for values in get_match_values:
            print(values.text)

Comment: At which line are you stuck?

Comment: for values in get_match_values:
            print(values.text)

Comment: I have two list from each loop and i want to make some calculation:    #wish my list was this
my_list = ["Chelsea", "2", "5", "223", "20:11"] #i have two list from selenium
club_name = list[1]
goals = ":"
newlist = []
for x in my_list:
  if goals in x:
    newlist.append(x)
    check_print = str(newlist)
    if goals == check_print[4]:
        score_1 = check_print[2:4]
        make_int = int(score_1)
        print(score_1)
    elif find == check_print[3]:
        score_2 = check_print[2]
        print(score_2)
  else:
      pass

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by using index to catch each of the strings.

```
    team1_list = []
    team2_list = []
    team2 = get_match_values[1]
    team2_list.append(team2)
    time.sleep(2)
    team1 = get_match_values[0]
    team1_list.append(team1)
    time.sleep(2)
    for y in team1_list:
        sco = y.text
        sc = sco.split()
```